# Double forward slash outputting as https:// in Tapcart App from Shopify Site

Tags: shopify

Working on a Shopify site for a client that utilizes tapcart, which appears to just grab default or inline styles from rich text editor. The problem lies in the product description where we use "//" as a divider.

`Product Description // This is a product` is how it is supposed to look. It instead appears as:

`Product Description https:// This is a product`

Not too familiar with how Tapcart works as they don't allow much outside development and can't give an answer as to why this is happening or if there is any way to avoid it. The error does not appear on the actual website. Is there a proper way to escape it? Has anyone seen something like this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop using the product description for stuff other than the product description and use metafields instead.

In the shopify admin go to settings -> metafields and define the metafields you need, then go to each product and use the metafields at the bottom rather than using the description to put additional info.